# How to make your c# app work as windows service?

Tags: c#, windows, service

How to make your c# app work as windows service? (matereals, todos wanted)

Comment: Three letters: [W C F](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Visual Studio "New Project window, select Windows Service.  This will set you up with a template which you can use to turn your app into a service.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Check out the Topshelf project. It was designed to do exactly this.

http://topshelf-project.com/

Answer (score 1):

To get some pointers on how to make a standalone WCF service, you can look at

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/1f62d283-f3aa-4c8e-a4ee-237e03801da9

You may want to start with having part of the app in IIS, and then as you get the web service fleshed out, then move it to your own application, removing the need for IIS.

That way you limit how much you actually need to debug at one time.

Answer (score 1):

There is lots of info about that on MSDN: [Windows Service Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y817hyb6.aspx)